# vTiger Event Handler to check if record exists

Tags: php, event-handling, vtiger

I am working on vTiger 6.5 and I am trying to figure a way to see if a record exists in a custom module of mine. I want to check whether the 'policynumber' is new before saving, here is my code so far. For some reason it seems to act randomly depending on my module number chosen.

```
class isaHandler extends VTEventHandler { 
function handleEvent($eventName, $entityData) {
    global $adb;
    $moduleName = $entityData->getModuleName(); 
    if($moduleName=='isa'){     
        if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable') {
            $isNew = $entityData->isNew('policynumber');
                    if ($isNew == false) {
                echo "Duplicate policy number";
                    exit;
        }
        }

        if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave') {}}
        if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave.final') {
            $price = $entityData->get('currentamount');
                    if($price > 20000){
                    echo "Please go back and enter less than 20000";
                    exit;
            }

        if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.aftersave') {}
    }   
}
```

At the moment I am currently using an echo just to see the result. But later on I will perform more than this.

Comment: `if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave') { //put your code inside this and try}`

Comment: @Bhaskar  I had previously tried this and I have just tried this again but I am still able to enter two of the same policy numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vTiger Custom Field Validation beforesave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144675/vtiger-custom-field-validation-beforesave)

Answer (score 0):

```
isNew()
```

Returns true if new record is being created, false otherwise. 
[More info is here](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Eventing)

you should write a custom query to check policynumber already exist or not in your function:

```
if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable') {
        global $adb;

$result = $adb->pquery("SELECT your-field-name FROM table_name WHERE policynumber=?", array($policynumbervalue));
if($result && $adb->num_rows($result)) {
  echo "This policy number exist";
  die();
    }else{
    // write your overwrite code
    }
  } //end if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable')
```

**Update:**

I am assuming there is field i.e. policynumber in your form, you enter some value in this field and submit the form. so you will get entered policy number value from this:

```
$policynumbervalue = $entityData->get('policynumber'); //this is vtiger standard way
```

if this does not work, you can simply use php global variable  `$_REQUEST['policynumber']` but I is not a good practice.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your respose @Bhaskar, here is what I have got, I am not sure what to put in `policynumbe=?` here is what I have so far:
`$result = $adb->pquery("SELECT policynumber FROM vtiger_isa WHERE policynumbe=?", array($policynumbervalue));
if($result && $adb->num_rows($result)) {
  echo "This policy number exist";
  die();
    }`

Comment: Thank you for your update @Bhaskar, here is what I now have although it does not seem to work. `$policynumbervalue = $entityData->get('policynumber');
$result = $adb->pquery("SELECT policynumber FROM vtiger_isa WHERE policynumber=?", array($policynumbervalue));
if($result && $adb->num_rows($result)) {
  echo "This policy number exist";
  die();
    }`

Comment: Just to let you know I also tried with `$_REQUEST['policynumber']`

Comment: @Diddy, I think this should work, do debugging. 1) `echo $entityData->get('policynumber');` getting policynumber? 2) run a query in DB `SELECT policynumber FROM vtiger_isa WHERE policynumber='put-here-policy-number'` and does it return any row in DB. if these are ok, check `$adb` by doing `print_r($adb);` . Hope You will get some to clue to fix yr problem!

Comment: thank you very much for your help, after doing some debugging I was able to alter the code slightly and get the result I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Diddy, sounds good, it would be great if you post solution too, that will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

This is the update to my answer, I simply done an if statement on the number of rows displayed.

```
    if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable') {

$policynumbervalue = $entityData->get('policynumber');
$sql = $adb->pquery("SELECT policynumber FROM vtiger_isa WHERE policynumber=?",array($policynumbervalue));
$nrows = $adb->num_rows($sql);
if($nrows > 0){
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('ISA policy number already exists, you will be redirected to the updata module.');
window.location.href = '/vtigercrm/index.php?module=isa&view=List';</script>"; 
    exit;
}
```